# EJB webservice hanging during first call in Websphere

Tags: performance, web-services, websphere, topdown

I have a top-down EJB Webservice (deployed on Websphere 6.01) that hangs the first time I call it after starting the JVM. If I see the logs, it seems to do everything normal that I expect it to (retrieving data from database) and I see all sysouts printed till the very last statement in EJB method. But client never gets the response back and eventually times out. Something is going on in the container (or in WS router application) after the control goes out of EJB but I don’t know how to troubleshoot it further. If it had something to do with startup, I would see slow down in the beginning of service invocation, not at the end.

From second call onwards it all works normal. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it is a problem with your connection in your datasource... Check your autoreconect option in your DS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibile directions:

1). Try stubbing out all the implementation of the EJB, no database calls, no work. See whether you still get the problem. If you don't, then presumably something interesting is happening in your code. If you do, then there's something weird happening in the infrastructure - probably PMR time.

2). WebSphere has plenty of trace you can turn on. Try enabling trace relating to Web container. This may let you see where it's getting stuck.

I would recommend opening a PMR anyway.